# Angular typescript jest test component with service and nested depndencies

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

I am trying to write test (and later need coverage too) for following component.

```
// Private class used by the component. do not want to test it.  
export class Summary {

  constructor(
    public vDate: Date,
    public bookName: string,
    .
    .
  ) {
    }
}

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor(
        private summaryService: SummaryDataService,
        public util: UtilService,
        private errorService: ErrorService,  
        private config: ConfigService,
        private refData: RefdataService,
      ) {
        this.innerHeight = 400; // (window.screen.height) / 1.6;
        this.errorMessage = null;
   }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    .
    .
    }
    
    handleUserSelection(selection) {
        console.log("Handle User Selection");
        console.log("Selection: " + selection.selectedDateTo.year);
        console.log("Selection: " + selection.selectedDateFrom.month);
        if (selection.selectedDateTo instanceof Date && selection.selectedDateTo.getTime()) {
          this.currentDateTo = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(selection.selectedDateTo);     
        } else {
          this.currentDateTo = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(new Date(selection.selectedDateTo.year,selection.selectedDateTo.month - 1,selection.selectedDateTo.day));
        }
        if (selection.selectedDateFrom instanceof Date && selection.selectedDateFrom.getTime()) {
          this.currentDateFrom = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(selection.selectedDateFrom);
        } else {
          this.currentDateFrom = this.util.formatCalendarDateToDateStr(new Date(selection.selectedDateFrom.year,selection.selectedDateFrom.month - 1,selection.selectedDateFrom.day));
        }

        console.log(selection);
        .
        .
        
    }
}
```

There are few services initialized at constructor.

I am trying to test:

```
describe('SummaryComponent', () => {

  let refdataService;
  let summaryDataService;    
  let component;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        SummaryComponent
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog, useClass: MatDialogMock },
         RefdataService,
         SummaryDataService,
      ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        RouterTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    refdataService = TestBed.inject(RefdataService);    
    summaryDataService = TestBed.inject(SummaryDataService);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SummaryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This fails as below:

```
  ? SummaryComponent > should create

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'environmentName' of undefined

      18 |     private runtimeConfig: RuntimeConfigService
      19 |   ) {
    > 20 |     this.environmentName = runtimeConfig.config.environmentName;
         |                                                 ^
```

The above code is actually from RefdataService.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RefdataService {
  environmentName = '';
  environmentUrl = '';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private runtimeConfig: RuntimeConfigService
  ) { 
    this.environmentName = runtimeConfig.config.environmentName;
    
  }
}
```

Basically the component (SummaryComponent) to test has RefDataService (in it's constructor) and that internally has call to object of RuntimeConfigService.

So, how to resolve this error?
Also, if we mock (how?) then how will coverage impact here?

As you see there is one method (handleUserSelection) which I will add to test after I resolve this issue. How to test that method to add in coverage (istanbul + jest)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide a mock `RuntimeConfigService` in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: RuntimeConfigService,
    useValue: {
      config: {
        environmentName: 'MOCK_VALUE',
      },
    },
  },
  // ...
],
```